# Angular ng-view in Cordova not work

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I am noob to angular and Cordova. I am developing a cordova application. I have the following code:

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']).
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: '/register.html',
            controller: 'registerController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home.html'
        })
})
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'authProvider', function ($rootScope, $location, authProvider) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
        if (!authProvider.isLoggedIn()) {
            alert('login');
            $location.path('/login')
        }
    });
}]).
factory('authProvider', function () {
    var user;
    return {
        setUser: function (aUser) {
            alert('set user');
            user = aUser;
        },
        isLoggedIn: function () {
            alert('is loged in');
            return (user) ? true : false;
        }
    };
});
```

And my index.js is as below:

```
var app = {
initialize: function () {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function () {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
},
receivedEvent: function (id) {
    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};
app.initialize();
```

And my index.html is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

<!--Shared Scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shared/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shared/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shared/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shared/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shared/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<!--Custom Scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/homeController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/loginController.js"></script>

<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-view></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I emulate my app in browser(`cordova emulate browser`), every thing is OK and `ng-view` works nicely, but when I run it on android device(`cordova run android`), `ng-view` does not work!

I have also tried to add :

```
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
```

to my app.js, but no success! I have also tried to define my `html` and `body` as below:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
```

or

```
    <body ng-app='myApp'>
```

But no success !

I am using AngularJs 1.5.8 and Cordova 6.2.0 and running my app on Android 4.0

**Updated**

After inspecting a Android 5.0 device, I found out that there is an error that saying:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///login.html
>   Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /login.html (HTTP
>   status: -1 )

Would you please help me solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think putting the `ng-app` directive on the `<head>` tag will work. Have you tried adding it to your `<html>` or `<body>` tag instead?

Comment: @Lex it was a writing mistake and I updated my question. I tried both, but still no success!

Comment: You can debug your app using google chrome, i.e. typing `chrome://inspect` at url place, and check if all your js files are being loaded.

Comment: @slackmart I am using Android 4.0, which is not supported for inspecting using Chrome://inspect

Comment: The docs say that android v4.0 and greater are supported: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en#requirements

Comment: @slackmart chrome://inspect recognized my device, but there is no inspect link showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution.

Just moving my views(`login.html` and `home.html`) into a folder(for example `views`) and add dot before my `UrlTemplate`

```
 $routeProvider
        //define the routes and their corresponded controllers
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: './views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: './views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: './views/register.html',
            controller: 'registerController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: './views/home.html'
        })
```